# Is there a way to determine if a page is compressed or not?

Tags: php, apache, gzip

I'm writing a script that can determine if a page is compressed or not, and I've been doing a bit of research and cannot figure out how to determine if a page is compressed. I'd assume that a page compressed would have something in the headers to say that it is a compressed file. Like Content-Type or something.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Odd I guess this url I'm using doesn't have compressed page although they swear it does. It's been driving me crazy! lol Thanks for the response I guess I'll go talk with the server people.

Comment: the server won't send back a compressed response unless the client says it can handle it (with e.g. `Accept-Encoding: gzip`). It's part of the HTTP content negotiation process. Could that be your problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually `Content-encoding`. Depending on the type of compression, this may be `gzip` (or `x-gzip`), `deflate` or `compress` in case of compressed data.

To cite [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#Other_uses):

> The “Content-Encoding”/"Accept-Encoding" and "Transfer-Encoding"/"TE" headers in HTTP/1.1 allow clients to optionally receive compressed HTTP responses and (less commonly) to send compressed requests. The specification for HTTP/1.1 (RFC 2616) specifies three compression methods: “gzip” (RFC 1952; the content wrapped in a gzip stream), “deflate” (RFC 1950; the content wrapped in a zlib-formatted stream), and "compress" (explained in RFC 2616 section 3.5 as 'The encoding format produced by the common UNIX file compression program "compress". This format is an adaptive Lempel-Ziv-Welch coding (LZW).'). Many client libraries, browsers, and server platforms (including Apache and Microsoft IIS) support gzip.

Answer (score 0):

Compressed page will have Content-Encoding header with compression algorithm.

For example:

Content-Encoding: gzip

Answer (score -1):

Do a http request with accepting gzip, and then analyse received headers, and look for Content-Encoding: gzip

Answer (score -1):

That's the web-browser which can see whether the page is compressed or not. As a web server Apache locates `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate` in HTTP request header. If it is present it compresses PHP script's HTML response and does compression accordingly.

Ref: http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/compress/